# Truncated Java object when passing through JAX-WS WebService

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, marshalling, classcastexception

I am currently working on a project that uses JAX-WS webservices in Java.
The global topic is this : the user creates locally an object, let's say an **Agent**. He calls a first **webservice** and passes its Agent to the webservice. The webservice treats the Agent (modifies its properties : e.g. lifepoints), and passes it to another webservice. This call is made from the first webservice, so the user has nothing to do in the process.

After a chain of several webservices, the user retrieves the Agent that has been modified.

The aim of my project is to design 2 parts:

- a *framework* that specifies the behaviour previously described : webservices, Agents and the process of migration
- a *demo application* using my framework. The main difference is the addition of a GUI and a new class **Avatar, that extends Agent**. So the migration process is still being done "by the framework", with Agent objects.

The following code shows a simple example of how I call my webservice, host my Avatar, then retrieves the agent from the service :

```
// connection to the server
URL endpoint= new URL("http://SERVER/tomcat/KiwiBidonDynamique/ServiceWebBidonDeDadou?wsdl");
QName serviceName=new QName("http://avatar/","ServeurKiwiBidonService");
Service service = Service.create(endpoint, serviceName);
WebService port = service.getPort(WebService.class);


Avatar myAvatar = new Avatar(1, "Jack the Ripper");
port.hostAgent(myAvatar);

// some process on the service...

Avatar myAvatarTransformed = (Avatar) port.getAgent("AgentNumberOne");
```

When I do that, I get an exception on the final line :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: agent.Agent cannot be cast to avatar.Avatar
```

---

After a lot of log reading, I guess the reason is the way the webservice works. When being called, my Avatar given in parameter is marshalled in my JVM then unmarshalled on the service, but **the service only constructs an Agent when it unmarshalles**. Doing so, it truncates the data specific to the Avatar. Then when I try to retrieve my Agent from the service, it cannot be cast to an Avatar.

Is there a way to keep the Avatar information while processing as an Agent on the service ?
Can I write my own marshalling/unmarshalling somehow ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your webservice has Agent element defined as incoming data, then no it is not possible to unmarshall it into an inherited class. I guess it would be possible to write your own marshaller but it is not as easy as it sounds (I would advise against it). Either write a separate WS for each class (messy) or make the incoming data have an element that can store additional structures, like type:any (also messy). The truth is WS are not exactly OO.

Comment: Thanks a lot. These were the options I was beginning to think of... I've been trying to implement custom marshalling with a XmlAdapter : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7282020/2291104