# Hyperjaxb: Exclude XML Element by XML property

Tags: java, jpa, xsd, hyperjaxb, xjb

I have a predefined XSD that looks as follows:

```
<xs:element name="JavaClass1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            ...
            <xs:element name="Date1" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="DateList1" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5">
            </xs:element>
            ...
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

In order to generate Java classes from XSD and at the same time replace XMLGregorianCalendar with `java.util.Date`, I used the following external binding:

```
<globalBindings>
    <javaType
        name="java.util.Date"
        xmlType="xs:dateTime"
        parseMethod="XsdDateTimeConverter.unmarshal"
        printMethod="XsdDateTimeConverter.marshalDateTime"
    />
    <javaType
        name="java.util.Date"
        xmlType="xs:date"
        parseMethod="XsdDateTimeConverter.unmarshal"
        printMethod="XsdDateTimeConverter.marshalDate"
    />
</globalBindings>
```

I found this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109608/how-replace-xmlgregoriancalendar-by-date).

Now, I need to do this only for the attribute **Date1** and not for **DateList1**. Is there a way how to exclude **DateList1** by using it's property `maxOccurs="5"`?

Comment: This `javaType` thingie has actually nothing to do with Hyperjaxb. That's pure JAXB functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the `javaType` customization locally to the generated property. Something like:

```
<bindings node=".../xs:element[@name='Date1']">
    <property>
        <baseType>
            <javaType .../>
        </baseType>
    </property>
</bindings>
```

Comment: The thing is, like **Date1** trhere are many other elements that must be customized. So I am looking for something like
 `<jaxb:bindings
  node="//xs:complexType[not(@name='Type1' or @name='Type2' ]">
  <hj:ignored /> 
 </jaxb:bindings>`
So exluding some elements, but not by name rather by a xml property. In this case _maxOccurs_.

Comment: Just modify the XPath and use `multiple="true"`.