# XMLGregorianCalendar to GregorianCalendar

Tags: java, date, timezone

I was simply trying to convert the instance of [`XMLGregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html) (which I got from JAXWS) to [`GregorianCalendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) in specific TimeZone using below code.

The date is coming in EST and I want to convert it into GMT for further saving to DB

```
//soap response <ns4:TimeStamp>2016-06-18T04:43:54-04:00</ns4:TimeStamp>
//dtime is what i got from JAXB for the above date, so I wrote::
Date date = dTime.toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US, null).getTime();
System.out.println(date);
```

Output: `Sat Jun 18 14:13:54 IST 2016`

Since above is not working as expected so i tried DateFormat and its giving the expected result.

```
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    GregorianCalendar gc =  dTime.toGregorianCalendar();
    System.out.println(df.format(gc.getTime()));
```

Output: `2016-06-18 08:43:54 +0000`

What could be the issue here as **toGregorianCalendar(...)** is not giving the desired result?

Also I noticed the GregorianCalendar instance obtained above from **toGregorianCalendar** has fieldSet= false. Not sure if this is causing the issue.

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1468382241000,**areFieldsSet=false,areAllFieldsSet=false**,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2016,MONTH=6,WEEK_OF_YEAR=29,WEEK_OF_MONTH=3,DAY_OF_MONTH=12,DAY_OF_YEAR=194,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=11,HOUR_OF_DAY=23,MINUTE=57,SECOND=21,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=-14400000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Any help will be appreciated..!!

Comment: How can the output be `05:27:21` if the input is `04:43:54`? Time zone changes will not affect the seconds.

Comment: sorry I mistakenly added the wrong outputs. Corrected now.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that Java [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) objects don't have a time zone. They are internally in UTC. Time zone only manifests when printed (formatted).

This simple code works:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.parse("2016-06-18T04:43:54-04:00");
GregorianCalendar cal = xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar();
java.util.Date date = cal.getTime();

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
System.out.println(format.format(date)); // prints: 2016-06-18 08:43:54
```

Since your goal is to save it to a database, you really don't care about formatting it to text. Assuming you're using JDBC (not some NoSQL), you need a [`Timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlCal = XMLGregorianCalendarImpl.parse("2016-06-18T04:43:54-04:00");
GregorianCalendar cal = xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar();
java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Now you can give that to a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) using [`setTimestamp()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTimestamp-int-java.sql.Timestamp-).

Comment: using this `xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()`  will not solve the purpose as this  is using the default server timezone. Whereas I want to have the date saved into GMT. So this is what I used. `xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"), Locale.US, null).getTime()` but this is not working.

Comment: @bbajaj `xmlCal.toGregorianCalendar().getTimeInMillis()` does **not** use the default server timezone. The `GregorianCalendar` will inherit the time zone from the `XMLGregorianCalendar`, which uses the time zone in the input string (`-04:00`). The `Timestamp` value doesn't have a time zone. It's internal value is always in UTC. Calling `date.toString()` will *render* the date in the default time zone, but that's for *rendering only*. The *value* of `date` is milliseconds since Epoch UTC (aka 1/1/1970).

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement
.setObject(                     // Exchange java.time objects with your database in JDBC 4.2 and later.
    … ,                         // Specify which `?` placeholder in your SQL statement.
    myXMLGregorianCalendar      // A legacy class. Better to use *java.time* whenever possible.
    .toGregorianCalendar()      // Convert from the one legacy class to another, as a bridge towards the modern `ZonedDateTime` class.
    .toZonedDateTime()          // Convert to the modern class.
    .toInstant()                // Adjust from a time zone to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
    .atOffset(                  // Adjust from basic `Instant` class to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class, if your JDBC driver does not offer the optional support for `Instant`. 
        ZoneOffset.UTC          // Specify UTC using this constant.
    )                           // Returns a `OffsetDateTime` object.
)
```

## *java.time*

You are using terrible old date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

> convert the instance of XMLGregorianCalendar (which I got from JAXWS) to GregorianCalendar

First call [`XMLGregorianCalendar::toGregorianCalendar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.xml/javax/xml/datatype/XMLGregorianCalendar.html#toGregorianCalendar()).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = myXMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar() ;
```

Convert from the legacy class `GregorianCalendar` to the modern `java.time.ZonedDateTime`. [Call the new conversion method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime()) added to the old class.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
```

> date is coming in EST and I want to convert it into GMT

The `java.time.Instant` class represents a moment in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), always in UTC. You can extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) from the [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Same moment, different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

> for further saving to DB

You *may* be able to pass an `Instant` to the database if your JDBC driver supports that. The `Instant` type is optional in JDBC 4.2.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , instant ) ;
```

If not supported, use `OffsetDateTime` as support is required by JDBC 4.2.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

> The date is coming in EST

`EST` is not a real time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following code to convert an `XMLGregorianCalendar` from a given source with a given timezone (e.g. GMT+0) to a `GregorianCalendar` with the current system timezone :

```
GregorianCalendar.from(xmlGregorianCalendar
    .toGregorianCalendar()
    .toZonedDateTime()
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()))
```

When you use only `XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()`, the returned `GregorianCalendar` has the same timezone as the source system, not the timezone of the current system. **Converting the timezone when you receive the data is safer**: this way, you reduce the number of potential issues in your code because all dates are based on the system timezone.

For example:

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendarFromSource = DatatypeFactory.newInstance()
    .newXMLGregorianCalendar("1983-09-30T23:00:00.000Z"); // the source system is on GMT+0
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendarWithSourceTZ = xmlGregorianCalendarFromSource.toGregorianCalendar();
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendarWithSystemTZ = GregorianCalendar.from(xmlGregorianCalendarFromSource 
    .toGregorianCalendar()
    .toZonedDateTime()
    .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault()));
System.out.println(xmlGregorianCalendarFromSource); // displays "1983-09-30T23:00:00.000Z" (i.e. GMT+0)
System.out.println(gregorianCalendarWithSourceTZ.toZonedDateTime()); // displays "1983-09-30T23:00Z[GMT]" (i.e. GMT+0)
System.out.println(gregorianCalendarWithSystemTZ.toZonedDateTime()); // displays "1983-10-01T00:00+01:00[Europe/Berlin]" (my system timezone is GMT+1 or GMT+2 depending on daylight saving)
```

Answer (score 0):

As another route, you could consider using Date's instead of XMLGregorianCalendars in your code by using jaxb bindings as discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109608/how-replace-xmlgregoriancalendar-by-date) stack overflow question.