# WSImport generates XMLGregorianCalendar instead of Date

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I am creating a SOAP web service, but stumbled on the following issue my DRO class looks the following, but when I create the service client for testing, in generated classes with WSImport, generated property type becomes XMLGregorianCalendar, How can I specify to WSImport not to change the data type?

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "players")
public class Players {
    List<Player> player;
    Date generated;

    @XmlAttribute
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    public Date getGenerated(){
        return this.generated;
    }

    public void setGenerated(Date value){
        this.generated = value;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<Player> getPlayer() {
        return this.player;
    }

    public void setPlayer(List<Player> value) {
        this.player = value;
    }
}
```

**EDIT** My current solution is based on [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106987/jax-ws-and-joda-time) I wonder if there is any other better ways to do it?

Comment: use bindings feature there is lot of example on internet