# Hyperjaxb: XMLGregorianCalendar to java.util.Date for Lists of Dates

Tags: java, hibernate, xsd, jaxb, hyperjaxb

I implemented the solution of [how replace XmlGregorianCalendar by Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109608/how-replace-xmlgregoriancalendar-by-date) but unfortunately it does not function for Lists of dates.
In my  XSD I have

`<xs:element name="Attribute1" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0">`
and

```
<xs:element name="Attribute2" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="5">
```

Attribute2 is a List of dates. If I load an Entity with this attribute I get an *java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentList incompatible with java.util.Date*

I think the problem is that, Hyperjaxb only creates an Adapter

```
public class Adapter2 extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{
    public Date unmarshal(String value) {
        return (XsdDateTimeConverter.unmarshal(value));
    }

    public String marshal(Date value) {
        return (XsdDateTimeConverter.marshalDate(value));
    }

}
```

Maybe Hyperjaxb also needs to create an Adapter for the `List<Date>` like `public class Adapter3 extends XmlAdapter<List<String>, List<Date>>`

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Regards
Erzen

PS: I've already seen the questions [Simple conversion between java.util.Date and XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679266/simple-conversion-between-java-util-date-and-xmlgregoriancalendar), [java.util.Date to XMLGregorianCalendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835889/java-util-date-to-xmlgregoriancalendar?lq=1) and [JAX-WS and Joda-Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5106987/jax-ws-and-joda-time) but those do not apply to my problem.

Comment: At the moment HJ3 does not support adapted types.

Comment: ok, thnx............